# Next.js - having trouble setting up an onClick handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was surprised when accessing `react.dev` saying that `create-react-app` is not any more suggested for a React application bootstrap.

All fine, the world changes, let's dig into Next.js for my first application...

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'

export default function Home() {

  function handleClick() {
    console.log("Clicked me!");
    alert("Clicked me!");
  }


  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.description}>
        <p>
          Get started by editing&nbsp;
          <code className={styles.code}>src/app/page.js</code>
        </p>
        <div>
          TESTE
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClick()}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Surprisingly I got the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: alert is not defined
```

I understand that Next.js has server-side rendering, but I cannot understand why I cannot use a simple alert to popup a browsers message.

Seems that there are new concepts I should start learning...

Why is my alert an error on Next.js?

Why is my `console.log` showing not on the browser but on the console?

Comment: You’re calling `handleClick` and passing its return value *(instead of the function reference )* to the button’s `onClick` property.

Comment: Fixed to onClick={handleClick}, but still not working (blank page). I'm confused here...

Comment: by default nextjs seems to render on server side, try adding `'use client'` at the top of your file. [ref](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when setting the `onClick`, you are calling `handleClick()`. You should instead pass its reference:

```
<button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
```

As you did, the function is getting called while rendering the component on the server, the reason why you were getting that error. And after doing as above, you will get a new error saying:

> If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component.

That's because, in the `app` directory, by default, Next.js uses [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#server-components), where the JSX gets compiled to "pure HTML" and sent to the browser, as you can read on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#why-server-components):

> Server Components allow developers to better leverage server infrastructure. For example, large dependencies that previously would impact the JavaScript bundle size on the client can instead **remain entirely on the server**, leading to improved performance. They make writing a React application feel similar to PHP or Ruby on Rails, but with the power and flexibility of React for templating UI.

And a Server Component shouldn't contain client-specific code, for example, click handlers. If you need that, you should add `"use client"` at the top, to make it a [Client Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components):

```
"use client";

import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'

export default function Home() {

  function handleClick() {
    console.log("Clicked me!");
    alert("Clicked me!");
  }


  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <div className={styles.description}>
        <p>
          Get started by editing&nbsp;
          <code className={styles.code}>src/app/page.js</code>
        </p>
        <div>
          TESTE
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a` works

```
+"use client";
+
 import Image from "next/image";
 import styles from "./page.module.css";
+import React from "react";
 
 export default function Home() {
+  const [score, setScore] = React.useState(0);
   return (
     <main className={styles.main}>
+      <a className={styles.center} onClick={() => setScore(score + 1)}>
+          <h2>
+            Score <span>-&gt;</span> {score}
+          </h2>
+      </a>
+
       <div className={styles.description}>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).